# How to spell "day hike" when it is used as a verb?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs, compounds

The compound noun "day hike" is used to describe ["a hike that can be completed in a single day"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiking#Related_terms). It is [most frequently written](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=day+hike%2Cdayhike%2Cday-hike&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cday%20hike%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdayhike%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cday%20-%20hike%3B%2Cc0) with a space in between the words, though you can find examples online where people have spelled it "dayhike" or "day-hike". Google automatically corrects searches for the word "dayhike" with "day hike".

Since "hike" is both a noun and a verb, "day hike" is commonly verbed, e.g. ["Or you can choose to day hike into the canyon."](http://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/day-hiking.htm)

Is that usage correct? [Here's the sentence](http://justinsomnia.org/2016/03/skyline-to-the-sea/) that triggered this question:

> To day hike any farther, I'm going to need longer days...

Should "day hike" be hyphenated in this case? Is there a general principle to follow in cases like these?

Answer (score 2):

> See http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/hyphen#hyphens_in_compound_words for the rules governing compound and phrasal nouns.

English is pretty dynamic and forgiving in this regard, so you needn't fear a raid by black-garbed Grammar Police if you hyphenate when you use **day hike** as a verb.

There seems to be little prepossessing reason to hyphenate ar blend **day hike**, though, so perhaps in this instance it would be best to heed the editorial preference of Google and leave the words separate.

Comment: I agree (like my opinion matters!). I feel only hyphenate as a compound adjective, like *that day-hike trail is totally steep, dude.*

Comment: @Rob_Ster, it's funny, your link seems to suggest that compound nouns used as verbs _should_ be hyphenated. They give "to ice-skate", "to booby-trap", "to spot-check", and "to court-martial" as examples, all of which are unhyphenated as nouns. "to day-hike" seems to fit the pattern exactly.